# Duplicate app when click in notification bar

Tags: android, android-activity, notifications, android-pendingintent

There's my code to display content to  notification bar :

```
NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
 PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                new Intent(this, MyActivity.class).putExtra("package.notification", 123).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK),
                PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher).setContentTitle("");
        // Set Big View style to see full content of the message
        NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle inboxStyle =
                new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle();
        inboxStyle.setBuilder(mBuilder);
        inboxStyle.bigText("");
        inboxStyle.setBigContentTitle("");
        inboxStyle.setSummaryText("");
        // Moves the big view style object into the notification object.
        mBuilder.setStyle(inboxStyle);
        mBuilder.setContentText(msg);
        mBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL);
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
```

onStart() in MyActivity.class

```
@Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (getIntent().getIntExtra("package.notification", -1) == 123) {
            //check in here
        }
    }
```

Issue is MyActitvity activity always created new when I click notification in  notification bar (duplicate activity if MyActitvity activity existed).

I want apps opening (it mean MyActitvity activity is active), not create MyActitvity new.

Only start MyActitvity activity when app closing (MyActitvity is not active)

Please to me advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are creating intent use this flag

```
Intent m_intent = new Intent(this, YourActivity.class);
m_intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
```

and then use this intent in pending intent

Answer (score 1):

You can use flag

```
 android:launchMode="singleTop"
```

in your activity in Manifest.xml:

```
            <activity
            android:name=[your_activity_name]
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme=[your_theme] />
```

Comment: Don't forget to override `onNewIntent(Intent)` in your activity if you need to .